# jscrollpane container acting like an iframe window?

Tags: jquery, plugins, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

if anyone has worked with jScrollpane plugin for jquery, then they would know that it creates a container `jspContainer` or something... However, I'm having problems displaying some items because this container acts like an iframe (or i think thats what its called)... basically, if I have a square div, and I've set it to an absolute position, and offset it say to the `left:-40px;` of the container, then part of the square div disappears.

Its acting as if this jspContainer is a window and any content showing outside of this container, it gets hidden... I've tried z-index:99999999999... but it still doesn't work.

I hope I'm explaining this clearly? Anyone else have this happen to them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because the container div is set to overflow hidden by default. This can be overridden by using something like:

```
 #myJspContainer{
      overflow:visible !important;

 }
```

Comment: Yes but if you use that CSS, there's no point of using jscrollpane, the overflowing content will also be visible!

Comment: @ComputerArts you would still get the custom scroll bar and functionality.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Did exactly what you told me. You were right, overflow was set to hidden, but i changed it to `visible !important;`but its still producing the same results? If you're using google chrome, when I click into the container, it has the border color orange as if it was an input field (if you know what I'm talking about)